# MVC Entity Relationship Mapping: Do I need a separate class(Admin) or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

Here is my mapping!

**User to Admin 1 to 0..1 relationship??**

Admin class has 2 properties: AdministratorID(Int) and AdministratorTitle(String)

One user can be one kind of admin status or no admin status

**Users to Tickets 1 to Many relationship??**

Users can open multiple tickets but a ticket can only be assigned to one User.

**Administrator to Ticket 1 to Many relationship??**

Admin (A user with admin status) has tickets assigned to him to fix. The ticket should have an AdminID to identify which admin is assigned to it .

The Ticket table should have: **TicketID**,**AdminID**(Admin assigned to fix it) and **UserID**(Person who created the ticket)

The User table should have : **UserID**, **AdminID**(0: Not an admin,1: Lvl 1 Admin, 2: Lvl 2 Admin) and **TicketID**(All the tickets that the User created)

The Administrator table should have: AdminID, UserID

My Question is do I need an Admin Class or not? Will I be able to show a table which has TicketID,UserID and AdminID(Shows the name of the User who is also an admin)

This is what I've done so far:

User.cs

```
   public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public int? AdministratorID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
        public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Administrator.cs

```
public class Administrator
{
    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    public string AdministratorTitle { get; set; }


    //  public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }


}
```

}

Ticket.cs

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }


    public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why would `Administrator` need a collection of `Ticket`s if the `User` already has them?

Comment: @GertArnold You might be correct! I followed a tutorial which showed a 1 to many relationship model and it had that. I'll update my question with my most up to date classes.

Comment: Now Administrator-User is 1:n. You're drifting. Maybe you should first make up your mind as to what exactly you want to model.

Comment: @GertArnold i re-edited the question. I don't think so? I followed this model to make it 1:0..1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479519/multiple-1-to-0-1-relationship-models

Answer (score 2):

Given that one admin has exactly one user, there is no need for a separate `Admin` class or table. The `User` already has an `Admin` flag, so you know which Users can and can't be assigned to a `Ticket`. The `Ticket` class becomes:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    //For Ticket to User relationship many to 1
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    //For Administrator to Ticket 1 to many relationship
    public int? Administrator{ get; set; }
    public virtual User Administrator { get; set; }
```

There is an FK relationship between `Ticket.AdministratorId` and `User.Id` and `Ticket.AdministratorId` will, I expect, be nullable to take care of the case when no-one is assigned as yet to the `Ticket`.

EDIT: As requested by  OP:

```
public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        // No separate Administrator class required
        public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
public class Ticket
{
    public int TicketID { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    // This "Administrator" is a User with IsAdministrator = true
    // A Ticket may or may not have an Administrator hence it is nullable.
    public int? AdministratorID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserID")]
    public virtual User Administrator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So I should delete my Admin class, put `public int adminID` in my UserClass? Could you copy my classes and re-edit them in your comment. I hope it's not asking too much because I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: No need for an `Admin` class... so what's the `Administrator` property in `Ticket` for?

Comment: The AdministratorId in Ticket is an FK to the User who has been assigned to the Ticket. Ticker already has a UserId in it pointing at the User who raised the ticket. There would not be an AdminId in User; I originally thought that there was a flag on user to say whether or not the user was an admin but re-reading it seems to be ambiguous. So I'll add that there should be a flag on the User indicating whether or not that user is an admin. I'll re-do the classes as you suggest.